# How to create the file handle in run time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to separate a file to 5 files , the first line will store in part1 , second line will store in part2

it is like this

```
#1 #6  ... to part1
#2 #7  ... to part2
#3 #8  ... to part3
#4 #9  ... to part4
#5 #10 ... to part5
```

I need to create five file handle for file1 to file5 , but it seems I can't use `(part+i)` as a file handle , I don't know which type should I convert to ? string?

How to solve this? thanks

here is my code

```
sys.argv[1] is source file  
sys.argv[2] is the directory to store  
sys.argv[3] is the number of subfile

import os
import sys

for i in range(1,sys.argv[3]+1):
    (part+i) = open(os.path.join(sys.argv[2],"part"+i),"w")

source = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
for idx,line in enumerate(source.readlines(),1):
    position = idx % int(sys.argv[3])
    if position == 0:
        (part+sys.argv[3]).write(line)
    else:
        (part+idx).write(line)

for i in range(1,sys.argv[3]+1):
    (part+i).close()
source.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with file handles and everything with trying to create variables dynamically.

The answer to that is: don't do that. [Keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Use a dictionary or list instead; the following list comprehension creates a list of open file objects:

```
files = [open(os.path.join(sys.argv[2], "part{}".format(i + 1)), "w")
         for i in range(sys.argv[3])]
```

Now you can address `files[0]`, `files[1]` and better still, loop over this list to access all open file objects `files[-1]` gives you easy access to the last file object, etc. etc.

Your loop looks a lot simpler now too, because now you can use 0-based indexing:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(source.readlines()):
    position = idx % int(sys.argv[3])
    files[position].write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list.

```
files = []
 ...
files.append(open(...))
 ...
files.append(open(...))
 ...
```